# Why is my cassandra throughput not improving when I add nodes?

Tags: cassandra

this is a newbie question. I have tried to do my homework, but I am stuck trying to learn how cassandra will scale linearly as advertized. When I run against a single cassandra node, I get reasonable insert rates. Here are some relevant bits of information:

- CentOS 6.5
- java 1.7.0_71
- cassandra 2.1.4 binary download
- data and commitlog on different drives
- compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 0
- 10,000,000 inserts
- Insertion rate: ~110K inserts/s
- Have not implemented [these settings](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/install/installRecommendSettings.html) yet, since I am not interested in making things blazing fast as much as in observing linear scaling.

My keyspace definitions is this:

```
create keyspace nms WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1' : 1 };
use nms;
CREATE TABLE RN(tableId int, sampleTime timestamp, sampleValue bigint, sampleStdev bigint, sampleRate bigint, tz_offset int,
       PRIMARY KEY (tableId, sampleTime));
```

My relevant java code looks like this (roughly):

```
cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("138.42.229.240")
                .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ANY))
                .withRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.INSTANCE)
                .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(new RoundRobinPolicy()))
                .build();
session = cluster.connect("nms");
batch = new BatchStatement();
statement = session.prepare("INSERT INTO RN" +
            "(tableId, sampleTime, sampleValue, sampleStdev, sampleRate, tz_offset)" +
            "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
```

I am inserting 32 tableIds (partition key), each "owned" by a single thread, and unique sampleTimes. The other data is filler junk.

I found the sweet spot to be ~10 inserts per batch and 10 executeAsync() call groups.

So far so good. Now, added 4 nodes, scrounging hardware and 3 VMs running on an SSD SAN (not ideal, I know). I used similar configuration for each node as what I described above and ran my simple test expecting some improvements. The insertion rate was unchanged. I cannot explain that. I would have expected some improvement. Moreover, the rate remains largely unchanged with 2, 3, 4 and 5 nodes. I realize that odd numbers probably make no sense, but I was desperate.

I then tried setting up the keyspace with a replication factor of zero. My data rates went down to 1K inserts/s. I cannot explain this. I must be missing something really obvious, but I cannot see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe inserting client app is maxed out, not the cluster? Could try using another machine and running the java code on that one as well and see if the throughput halves or is same for both clients.

Comment: It looks like you nailed it. I added more clients and my throughput is up to ~170K/s. What is interesting is that all my clients really hammer their CPUs regardless of the rate. I would have expected some waiting to alleviate the CPU of the clients as they stress the servers. On the other hand, the cassandra servers are busy, but do not seem hammered. I probably need to optimize the servers now, I imagine. Thanks for your help. You get the answer credit since you responded first ;-)

Answer (score 4):

1) You may be maxing out the inserting client, as Chris suggested.

2) You're running VMs on a SAN, which shares IO bandwidth between all of the VMs. In effect, you're not adding capacity as much as distributing load between more virtual replicas sharing the same resources.

3) Batches aren't typically intended for speed as much combining multiple statements into single logical operations. You're putting a lot of work on your coordinator, which will eventually hurt scaling: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html

Comment: Re: 2, I found more hardware, a smallish box, but it is not doing anything else. I am going to try that.
Re: 3, that is what I would have expected, but my overall throughput got better with batches. I will experiment some more with just one of the VMs and more cpu/memory.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Do the inserts within your batch not share the same partition key (tableId)?  If they do not each insert in the batch with a unique partition key is treated as a separate mutation on the cassandra node that handles your request and it needs to send those mutations to the responsible replicas.   As your cluster size grows this may actually degrade performance as more replicas need to be contacted to complete your batch.

If you keep your batches to a single partition per batch, or not use batches at all, you should get improved performance with more nodes.  See ['Batch Loading without the Batch'](https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/08/28/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword/) keyword as a good reference on how to optimize this.

With regards to losing performance with a lower replication factor, this is because when you reduce the replication factor a replica has less of a representation of the data in the cluster and thus could not service as much of your request if it spread out among partition keys.

Comment: Yes @Andy, my batches are all for the same partition key (tableId). Each of my 32 threads generates inserts for the same tableId (0-31). I had seen the reference you point out. I will study it more carefully. Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: Ah, cool thanks for confirming @JulioGarcia.  I think Chris' response may be a good thing to look into then.