# Why is my client CPU utilization so high when I use a cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra

This is a follow-on question to [Why is my cassandra throughput not improving when I add nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29566102/why-is-my-cassandra-throughput-not-improving-when-i-add-nodes). I have configured my client and nodes as closely as I could to what is recommended here: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/install/installRecommendSettings.html. The whole setup is not exactly world class (the client is on a laptop with 32G of RAM and a modern'ish processor, for example). I am more interested in developing an intuition for the cassandra infrastructure at this point.

I notice that if I shut down all but one of the nodes in the cluster and run my test client against it, I get a throughput of ~120-140 inserts/s and a CPU utilization of ~30-40%. When I crank up all 6 nodes and run this one client against them, I see a throughput of ~110-120 inserts/s and my CPU utilization gets to between ~80-100%.

All my tests are run with a clean DB (I completely delete all DB files and restart from scratch) and I insert 30M rows.

My test client is multi-threaded and each thread writes exclusively to one partition using unlogged batches, as recommend by various sources for a schema like mine (e.g. https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/08/28/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword/).

Is this CPU spike expected behavior?

Comment: When you bring up the additional node that has been down for a while, it is probably getting pelted by hinted handoffs. When one node is down, other nodes will accumulate hints (store the data in system.hints table) and will send them to the node when it comes back up. This will create additional work (cpu and otherwise), while that node catches back up.

Comment: Does your program monitor the number of in flight requests? How big are your writes?

Comment: @phact: Your first observation makes sense. I should not start from scratch, it sounds like. I am not sure how to monitor the in-flight requests. My batch size is 8 and I executeAsync() 16 of these before calling getUninterruptibly() to let the nodes catch up to my client. I have observed that batches between 8-10 and execureAsync() sets of 10-16 yield the fastest times. Is this what you are asking? Thank you.

Comment: Yep, here's a couple of reference implementations you can take a look at -- Ryan Svhila https://github.com/rssvihla/dse_driver_examples/blob/e4fd555478bc5dfcbc999e039364f5d80ad0018a/src/main/java/pro/foundev/bulk/BulkLoader.java#L102-L113  Brian Hess - https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader/blob/60c8b595b117f7b0c7de2f3b9ddbc899ad5bdd9b/src/main/java/com/datastax/loader/CqlDelimLoad.java#L483

Comment: By start from scratch what do you mean?

Comment: When I "start from scratch", do this: sudo rm -fr /opt/cassandra/data/*/* /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/* && sudo /opt/cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.1.4/bin/cassandra -f. P.S. I tried a few more runs without starting from scratch and my times seem to have improved for the single client and the CPU utilization went to ~40-60%. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: You should see an increase in performance for fresh clusters with larger nodes. Are you saying you only see the increase in performance when you add a node to a live system?

Comment: No what I mean is that I may be seeing a slight increase in throughput and a noticeable decrease in CPU utilization when I simply re-run my test against the same 6 nodes without purging the DB files. Does that make sense?

Comment: I guess if the cluster hasn't quite settled from starting up which is a high cpu activity. Otherwise, I can't think of why a new environment would differ from an existing one based on the cassandra write path- http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_write_path_c.html?scroll=dml_write_path_c__dml-compaction