# Why is my cassandra insert rate better with a client/node in the same host than with client and one node in separate hosts?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

This is a followup question to this one: [Why is my cassandra throughput not improving when I add nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29566102/why-is-my-cassandra-throughput-not-improving-when-i-add-nodes)

My schema currently looks like this (the blobs are roughly all the same size, about 140 bytes):

```
create keyspace nms WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1' : 1 };
use nms;
CREATE TABLE qos(
                hour timestamp,
                qos int,
                id int,
                ts timestamp,
                tz int,
                data blob,
              PRIMARY KEY ((hour, qos), id, ts));
```

In both scenarios, I have a single node. Other than the obvious IP address and storage locations, the Apache C* 2.1.5 config is out of the box.

When I run the client and single node in separate hosts, I get roughly 55K inserts/s. The cfhistograms output looks roughly like this:

```
nms/qos histograms
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)
50%             0.00             86.00              0.00             42510               535
75%             0.00            124.00              0.00             42510               642
95%             0.00            179.00              0.00             61214              1109
98%             0.00            215.00              0.00             61214              1109
99%             0.00            258.00              0.00             61214              1109
Min             0.00              4.00              0.00               150                 3
Max             0.00          61214.00              0.00             61214              1109
```

When I run the client on the same host as the single node, I get roughly 90K inserts/s. A histogram snapshot looks like this (pretty much the same above):

```
nms/qos histograms
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)
50%             0.00             86.00              0.00             42510               535
75%             0.00            103.00              0.00             42510               642
95%             0.00            179.00              0.00             61214              1109
98%             0.00            310.00              0.00             61214              1109
99%             0.00            535.00              0.00             61214              1109
Min             0.00              3.00              0.00               150                 3
Max             0.00         126934.00              0.00             61214              1109
```

Why the big difference in insertion rates? I would have thought the rates would be equivalent, or better in the split setup?

BTW, I see this odd behavior with all the permutations of hardware that I have available to me, so there is more to it than client horsepower.

Comment: consider this an equivalency: why does it take longer to get a drink when I have to drive to the store, compared to when I just get something from the fridge"?

Comment: Not quite equivalent. If I add another node in the same network, rates essentially double. If your analogy were to hold, then it would point to network latency, but I do not observe that to be the problem.

Comment: there's more than just insertion rates. e.g. if each insertion is a separate connection to the db, then you have login overhead, tcp connection overhead, dns overhead, blah blah blah.

Comment: No, the client has a single connection for my test, which inserts 100M records. That overhead would outlive us for a data set of that size, if I were doing it per insert :-D. The inserts finish in ~20 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marc B, you are correct. If you see this and would like to post your comment as an answer, I will give you credit for it.

In more detail, what was happening is that while my connection to the network was 1G, I was going through an unexpected 100Mb router somewhere. Once I realized this and ensured all the moving parts were in the same 1G network, my rates jumped to 180K inserts/s.

In case someone cares, the Linux command to check you interface speed is

```
sudo ethtool eth0
```

The tool to test the speed between boxes is [iperf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7976/how-do-you-test-the-network-speed-betwen-two-boxes).